# Creating new columns in Python using index value

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I have a 50x50 dataframe filled with 1's. I used the melt function to create a long dataframe where the first column represents the index value.

```
    X   Y   value
0   0   0   1.0
1   1   0   1.0
2   2   0   1.0
3   3   0   1.0
... ... ... ...
29  29  0   1.0
... ... ... ...
2470 20 49  1.0
2471 21 49  1.0
2472 22 49  1.0
... ... ... ...
2498 48 49  1.0
2499 49 49  1.0
```

From the original 50x50 matrix, if I start at x=0 and y=0 (with x being my columns and y being my rows) and move up a position, then I am at x=0, y=49. From the melted dataframe, x=0 and y=49 is associated with index number 2450. I want to create a new column where the corresponding index number is represented so that I have:

```
    X   Y   value index_value
0   0   0   1.0       2450
```

I have tried:

```
df["index_value"] = df.loc[df['X'], df['Y']] = '((Y-1)*50 + X)'
```

But I get this error:

```
KeyError: '[0 0 0 ..., 49 49 49] not in index'
```

I may be able to use the groupby function, but any other help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I noticed there is a pattern in the index associated with the x,y values and I tried creating a function to represent the index, and then shift that value, however I am not sure where to begin and I believe there is a simpler way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the values in the column "index_value" should depend on the indices of the the entry in the original 50x50 DataFrame. The relationship is ((Y-1)*50 + X)

The indices of the new DataFrame also depend on the indices of the 50x50 DataFrame. The relationship is ((Y)*50 + X)

It can be seen that the new column with needed values can be created by shifting the index of the melted DataFrame by 50 rows. So,

reset_index() adds a new column index which is the index of the dataframe

```
>>>df=df.reset_index()
```

np.roll shifts the numbers by 50 rows

```
>>>df['index']=np.roll(df['index'],50)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17704996)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the df.reset_index() method. This will reset the index and create a new column called 'index'

Example:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=False)
```

Comment: I don't wish to create a new column called index. The new column I want to create needs to reflect the index value based on the new position.